# printing an image in landscape orientation?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I am converting a control to a bitmap and print it:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    chart1.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Bmp);
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);

    PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
    doc.PrintPage += (s, ev) =>
    {
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, Point.Empty); // adjust this to put the image elsewhere
        ev.HasMorePages = false;
    };

    doc.Print();
}
```

How can you specify to print it in landscape orientation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
doc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.landscape.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Through the [`PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.defaultpagesettings.aspx) browsable property.

```
PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
```

So, for your code sample, this would be:

```
doc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
```